# arrow::open_dateset not evaluating skip_rows in R

Tags: r, csv, bigdata, parquet, apache-arrow

I am trying to read in a large number of .csv files using arrow as the data are too big to work with as they are. In each file the first 2 rows contain metadata only in one column. I am trying to skip these 2 rows and evaluate the rest of the data but I am met with:

```
Error in `open_dataset()`:
! Invalid: Error creating dataset. Could not read schema from 'path': Could not open CSV input source 'path': Invalid: CSV parse error: Row #3: Expected 1 columns, got 296: col1, col2, col3, .... Is this a 'csv' file?
```

my data also does not have column names, I am wondering if this is the issue with reading the schema?

I can't provide sample data as I am not able to create a dummy data frame with 1 column in rows 1:2 and >1 column in rows 3:end, but after the first 2 rows it is just a 296 x 507 grid of decimal values.

The code I have tried to read my files is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)

dir.create("converted_parquet")
csv_data <- open_dataset("path", format = "csv",
                          partitioning = schema("date" = date32(),
                                                "time" = time32("s")), 
                          skip_rows = 2)

write_dataset(csv_data, "converted_parquet", 
              format = "parquet", 
              partitioning = c("date", "time")
```

I also think there may be an issue in `partitioning = schema(...)` in my code because my files do not have 'Hive-style' names for partitioning and I would like to index which part of the file name to use for "date" and "time"

i.e. my file names are formatted: "my_file_Time[yyyymmddThhmmss].csv"
I would like to extract "yyyymmdd" for "date" and "hhmmss"" for "time"

I thought this could be done by indexing the character position in the string with `$field(16:23)` for date and `$field(25:30)` for time, but unsure where this should go.

**Is anyone able to suggest a way to open a large list of csv files and omit the first rows?
I have read them in using `data.table::fread` but the data are too big to work with from .csv files for my PC's RAM. Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

Up front, I don't know of a way to get `arrow::open_dataset` to honor what most other csv/tsv-file reading functions use as `header=` or `col_names=`.

Creating a normal (with-headers) file as

```
aaa,bbb
---,---
5.974,0.5
6.15,0.475
5.806,-0.083
5.694,0.944
```

I can readily read that file with `open_dataset("quux.csv") %>% collect()`. (Note: I know that this doesn't perfectly represent your data, as you said that it has varying number of columns ... I'm just going with the premise of getting what you need after skipping rows.)

If I skip the first 2 rows, then obviously the names are askew and we don't have usable column names.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(arrow)
open_dataset("~/Downloads/quux.csv", format = "csv", skip_rows = 2) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   `5.974`  `0.5`
#     <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1    6.15  0.475
# 2    5.81 -0.083
# 3    5.69  0.944
```

What we can do is read in the first row of values, convert that to meaningful types, and name the resulting dat.

```r
nms <- c("aaa", "bbb") # determine this how you want
ds <- arrow::open_dataset("~/Downloads/quux.csv", format = "csv", skip_rows = 2)
row1 <- ds %>%
  slice_head(n = 1) %>%
  collect()
row1
# # A tibble: 1 × 2
#   `5.974` `0.5`
#     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    6.15 0.475
row1[] <- Map(`class<-`, names(row1), sapply(row1, class))
names(row1) <- nms
row1
# # A tibble: 1 × 2
#     aaa   bbb
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  5.97   0.5
ds %>%
  collect() %>%
  setNames(nm = nms) %>%
  bind_rows(row1, .)
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#     aaa    bbb
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  5.97  0.5  
# 2  6.15  0.475
# 3  5.81 -0.083
# 4  5.69  0.944
```

Notes:

1. I set the names manually here; it is possible you can derive them programmatically based on the file (perhaps just `nms <- names(read.csv("quux.csv", nrows = 1))`).
2. If you have more complex column classes (e.g., `POSIXt`), then you might need a little more work on the `Map`ing to assign appropriate classes to `row1`.
3. My last step was to `collect` the whole frame, since I wanted to combine `row1` with the real data. Unfortunately, `bind_rows` does not appear to work on combining `DataSet` and `data.frame` objects, so that step was necessary. You may have more specific needs with how to deal with `row1` in your larger queries/piping.

---

Ultimately, though, this should be handled more easily once `col_names` is supported, since currently it is not:

```r
arrow::open_dataset("quux.csv", format = "csv", skip_rows = 2, col_names = FALSE)
# Error: The following option is supported in "read_delim_arrow" functions but not yet supported here: "col_names"
```

We just need to stay-tuned ...

Comment: Hi @r2evans thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I can't get my data to open at all without somehow skipping the first 2 rows as there are a different number of rows in the rest of the dataset. The error I get reads: 

Error in `open_dataset()`:
! Invalid: Error creating dataset. Could not read schema from 'path/file.csv': Could not open CSV input source 'path/file.csv': Invalid: CSV parse error: Row #3: Expected 1 columns, got 296: .... Is this a 'csv' file?

Comment: I'm confused by *"different number of rows in the rest of the dataset"* ... do you mean that in the rest of that CSV files, there are different numbers of _columns_? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: no, so the first 2 lines contain metadata that is only in column 1 with no headings or anything and then the actial data is contained in rows 3 up so more like `aaa; bbb; 1,2,3,4; 1,2,3,4; 1,2,3,4 ` (where ; denotes line change and , is normal comma separation)

Comment: Okay, well, I can't fix what I can't see. Your question is unfortunately not reproducible (and the code in my answer is, so it is obviously fixing the wrong problem). If you can make it reproducible (sample data that reproduces the error), it would be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to start reading the dataset with the row that contains specific keywords(i.e., similar to skip argument in data.table::fread)?

Comment: I don't think so. In fact, I did not know that `fread` supported `skip="string"`, that's new to me.